# Upload CSV file how to remove extra spaces

Tags: php, csv, upload, whitespace

How can I remove extra white spaces between words on upload of file

```
// Allow certain file formats
if($fileType != "csv" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only CSV files are allowed. ";
}
else {
    if (isset($_POST['master'])) {
        (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_master));
    }
    if (isset($_POST['janb1'])) {
        (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file_janb1));
    }
}
```

This is part of my csv results note the extra spaces between Stockwell    Constr - should only have one space

```
07-01-2020,Pitstop Couriers,-2377.05,7313.5
07-01-2020,Stockwell       Constr,-1993.56,5319.94
07-01-2020,Sphe Salary,-500,4819.94
07-01-2020,Frans Salary,-200,4619.94
07-01-2020,Job Salary,-200,4419.94
```

Answer (score 0):

The workflow using [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) should be the correct way. You would get back a pointer which allows you to call `foreach` on the rows. From there all you would want to do is run a `preg_replace($cell_content, /s+/, “ “)` to replace any white space with a single space. Not sure what is happening in your function to have caused the addition of tab-sized white space, but it will possibly be reading out some form of “\t” character from the document itself.